# My object won’t move in render

Tags: modeling, transforms

My object/model will move in blender but it will go back to its original spot (the spot it originally was placed at when I opened it in blender)when it’s rendering. I’m not sure if I did something but my camera will move but my object/model stays the same. What do I do!

Comment: Hmmm .  Suggestion ... place a Blender screen shot in your question.  Show as much as possible.  Show Keyframes, Modifiers, including Geometry Nodes, Constraints.  Take a look at your [keyframes] for your object/model.  I think you can place more effort into your question.

Comment: have you keyframed your object? It could explain why it goes back to a location